# Gremlin Search for vertices and add property at run time

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

My query is quite simple but I do not know how to perform this in gremlin. I could perform the same in cypher.
I have a many persons in  my graph. Some of them are friends . I want to find persons based on their properties but at the same time check if they are friends against a given node id and if they are , when the resultset is being prepared, add a boolean that they are friends to the output.
So if I have

> V(4192), V(4268),V(4986),V(4966), V(10200),V(12004)

> and I am finding against V(4192).

All the nodes have their last name as **"Das"**. V(4268) and and V(4986) are friends with V(4192).

I will be searching with last name "Das". I am expecting that all nodes are part of output with a property **friends=true** is appended to each row of resultset if they are friends.

Comment: I tried to make one though "g.V().has("lastName","Das").project("id","firstName","lastName","inFriend","outFriend").by().by("firstName").by("lastName").by(inE("friend_of").where(V().hasId(4192)).fold()).by(outE("friend_of").where(V().hasId(4192)).fold())  " , it prints additional relationships which I would like to remove with a boolean

Comment: I think I arrived to a solution, not the exactly required one but would do the job. " g.V().has("lastName","Das").project("id","firstName","lastName","inFriend","outFriend").by().by("firstName").by("lastName").by(inE("friend_of").where(otherV().hasId(4192)).count()).by(outE("friend_of").where(otherV().hasId(4192)).count())
  "

Comment: If you are able to provide some `addV` and `addE` steps that build a sample graph and an example of the desired output that will make it easier to suggest improvements.